# Are Planned Parenthood videos edited to distort truth?

Tags: medical-science

In [this NPR story](http://www.npr.org/2015/09/29/444398818/amid-controversy-head-of-planned-parenthood-testifies-before-lawmakers) the point is made that the videos released by *The Center for Medical Progress* are heavily edited. Even the longer versions are supposedly edited. This is supposedly done so that it hides the real facts behind the sale of fetal tissue.

According to [this article on Fox News](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2015/09/29/forensic-analysis-planned-parenthood-videos-show-no-evidence-manipulation/?intcmp=hpbt1), there was a review that showed the longer versions were not edited.

So, are the longer versions of the Planned Parenthood videos edited in a way that distorts the truth?

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/28/us/abortion-planned-parenthood-videos.html?_r=0

Comment: "Distorting the truth" is a pretty vague claim, as in a sense, all editing is an intentional "distortion" of the truth (if only to make long events appear to pass more quickly). This isn't a direct criticism of the question (I'm not down voting).  If you can think of a reasonable way to modify the question to be more specific, that would make it better though, IMO.

Comment: This question has two issues which I hope we can fix to re-open. The first is that - as worded - it is a question about motivation, which can never be definitively answered, so is off-topic. The second is that it is very broad. Take a specific claim from the videos and ask whether that claim is true - not what was going on in the head of the producer at the time.

Comment: The question of motivation _can_ be answered (if it happened) if people involved confess they did so, and include their reasons.

Comment: @SQB not really. That's just another claim that can be equally doubted.

Answer (score -2):

https://drjengunter.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/obgyns-agree-fully-formed-fetus-in-that-planned-parenthood-video-not-from-an-abortion-heres-why/

This is a gynecologist showing that one of the images in the 3rd video is not what they claim it is.  While it's only one fabrication such things rarely travel alone.

Edit:

https://drjengunter.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/the-center-for-bio-ethical-reform-promotes-illegally-taped-video-of-perineum-and-premature-delivery-and-fiorina-supports-them/

More from her:  The procedure doesn't match current US medical practice.  Either it's very old or it was shot in some other country.

Comment: I'd like to see better evidence than a single expert opinion, especially on a hot topic like abortion.

Comment: Downvoters, how about an explanation?